# Finding mongodb records in batches using mongoid

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails, database, mongodb

I want to get records in batches. But mongoid doc says to avoid using skip due as it can be expensive. I wrote this method to iterate through a large number records efficiently.

```
module Mongoid
  module Batches
    def find_each(batch_size = 1000)
      return to_enum(:find_each, batch_size) unless block_given?
      find_in_batches(batch_size) do |documents|
       documents.each { |document| yield document }
     end
   end
   def find_in_batches(batch_size = 1000)
     return to_enum(:find_in_batches, batch_size) unless block_given?
     documents = self.asc(:created_at).limit(batch_size).asc(:id).to_a
     while documents.any?
       documents_size = documents.size
       primary_key_offset = documents.last.id

       yield documents
       break if documents_size < batch_size
       documents = self.where(:id.gt => primary_key_offset).asc(:created_at).limit(batch_size).asc(:id).to_a
     end
   end
 end
end
Mongoid::Criteria.include Mongoid::Batches
```

Comment: Please find an answer there : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7041224/finding-mongodb-records-in-batches-using-mongoid-ruby-adapter

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is no need to take this way since mongodb cursor by defaults returns batchwise

Comment: This answer deserves more explication and a link to the documentation of `batch_size` for instance

Answer (score 0):

This code is buggy.Would result in duplicates